# Any disadvantage of using window.document.title in angular 5?

Tags: dynamic, angular5, title

Browser title needs to be updated dynamically and i have used window.document.title in individual component to update the title which is absolutely working fine.

But i can see other solutions outside to use title service and subscribe to router events and then set the title which doesn't seem to be a simple solution for me.

Is there any disadvantage of using window.document.title?

What is the better approach? Thanks in advance.